# How do I weed out invalid results from an amazon api query

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm using this function to request books from amazon that are priced at 0 but I am getting three different responses.

Some books are listed at 0

- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B009EFZQV0/?tag=centsme-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009EFZQV0)

Some have a price

- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A3H57CG/?tag=centsme-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A3H57CG)

And others have a price but are free for prime members

- can't find an example now

Now I looked at the source of the page and noticed multiple values for price and that I need the id pricelarge and listprice to both be 0. The faq doesn't help me at all and I'm getting stumped on how to fix this.

This is the query function I'm using now.

> $search = new Search();
>
> $conf->setRequest('\ApaiIO\Request\Soap\Request');
>
> $conf->setResponseTransformer('\ApaiIO\ResponseTransformer\ObjectToArray');
>
> $search->setCategory('MobileApps');
>
> $search->setMaximumPrice(0);
>
> $search->setPage($page);
>
> $search->setBrowseNode($bid);
>
> $search->setSort('reviewrank');
>
> $search->setResponseGroup(array('ItemAttributes','ItemIds', 'Images'));
>
> $formattedResponse = $apaiIO->runOperation($search, $conf);

Comment: Could you post an example of the results from the query?

Comment: Here's the response I get.

http://shrib.com/8JGXciQM

Answer (score 0):

For the response, I would also grab a price variable. That way you can double check the price of the item before you present it to your user.

Comment: When doing an ItemSearch request the only variables I have to work with are.


- Author

- BrowseNode

- Condition

- ItemPage

- Keywords

- MaximumPrice

- MerchantId

- MinimumPrice

- Power

- Publisher

- Sort

- Title

Maybe I can have it return a price listing and I can then add it to the DB. From that I can have the page pull items that match the two ID's that I know match the right price.